# WebView2 Source property CoreWebView2 is null

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2, microsoft-edge-chromium

> ```
> Namespace: Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms
> Assembly: Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.dll
> Package: Microsoft.Web.WebView2 v1.0.902.49
> ```

```
string userDataFolder = Path.GetTempPath() + @"WebView2UserData";
CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions();
```

> Webview Intialization

```
async void InitwebView()
{
    CoreWebView2Environment env = CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync("", userDataFolder, options).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
    webView.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebView_CoreWebView2Ready;
}
```

> Sending Post Data through webView

```
 public void SendPostData(string url, string postData, string headers)
    {
     byte[] postDataByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
     MemoryStream postStream = new MemoryStream(postDataByte);
     string additionalHeaders = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" + 
     Environment.NewLine + headers;
     this.webView.Source = new Uri(url);
```

> Navigating with WebResourceRequest

```
var request = webView.CoreWebView2.Environment.CreateWebResourceRequest(url,"POST",postStream, additionalHeaders);           
    webView.CoreWebView2.NavigateWithWebResourceRequest(request);
}
```

Comment: When is `Source` null? BTW: Don't use `async void`, since that will not await.

Comment: Hi, @Poul Bak - On CreateWebResourceRequest webView.CoreWebView2 property is null

Comment: Try using `async Task` and `await` the call.